# Why does Xcode 4 not throw a warning over my incomplete implementation of the UITableViewDataSource protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

If I declare and incompletely implement my own protocol using the following code in Xcode:

> SomeProtocol.h:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>

@required

-(void)someRequiredMethod;

@end
```

> SomeImplementor.h:

```
#import "SomeProtocol.h"

@interface SomeImplementor : NSObject <SomeProtocol>

@end
```

> SomeImplementor.m:

```
#import "SomeImplementor.h"

@implementation SomeImplementor { // I get a warning on this line

}

@end
```

Then Xcode throws a warning on the `@implementation` line of SomeImplementor.h, that reads as follows:

> Incomplete implementation.
>
> Method 'someRequiredMethod' in protocol not implemented.

However, if I incompletely implement the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol from UITableView.h with the following code...

> SomeClass.h:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

> SomeClass.m:

```
#import "SomeClass.h"

@implementation SomeClass  { // I think I should get a warning here, but I don't

}

@end
```

... then Xcode is fine with it, and doesn't display a warning anywhere, even though I clearly haven't implemented the following methods from the UITableViewDataSource protocol:

```
@protocol UITableViewDataSource<NSObject>

@required

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Why? I can't see any reason that these two cases should be treated differently. (And I want my warnings!)

Comment: @MarkAmery Very interesting. I'm seeing the same results.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038381/compile-warnings-about-missing-required-protocol-methods-not-appearing

Comment: @Jai: But note that that question has no accepted answer, and this question adds more valuable information. So I would recommend **NOT** to close as a duplicate.

Comment: It occurs to me that a useful next step in researching this puzzle would be to check whether the lack of warnings applies to all protocols with required methods defined in UIKit, or just to UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I added `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`: no warning.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Now something new: Adding the `NSCopying` or `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol produces a warning! - (NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate was a bad example, because all methods are optional.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug in Xcode 4.

It appears to be fixed in Xcode 5, which warns you appropriately.

Comment: I wish I had an old Xcode install with iOS 4 SDK. I am pretty sure that I saw warnings about incomplete implementation in UITableViewController subclasses. But that was a long time ago, so I'm not sure if that really happened or if I make that up.